# ms access: Empty subform query causes empty parent control reference

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, controls, subform

**The Problem**

I have two continuous subforms A and B in a tabular layout on a main form C. The first has the names of some chemicals, the second has corresponding info on those chemicals. I have a field D on C that takes the value of the primary key [stoff_id] of A for the current record. B is linked to D, so it shows all corresponding records for the currently selected chemical. Here a quick overview of the database:

*[DB Relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5vZw.png)*

**The query for A [stoffe_abfrage subform]:**

```
SELECT chemikalien_tabelle.stoff_id, chemikalien_tabelle.bezeichnung, 
chemikalien_tabelle.einsatzgebiet, kategorie_tabelle.kategorie
FROM kategorie_tabelle INNER JOIN chemikalien_tabelle ON 
kategorie_tabelle.[kategorie_id] = chemikalien_tabelle.[kategorie_id];
```

**The query for B [tmb_abfrage subform]:**

```
SELECT tmb_tabelle.version, tmb_tabelle.datum_aktualisiert, 
tmb_tabelle.datum_upload, sprachen_tabelle.bezeichnung, 
tmb_link.stoff_id, tmb_link.tmb_id, tmb_tabelle.datei.FileType, 
tmb_tabelle.datei
FROM (sprachen_tabelle INNER JOIN tmb_tabelle ON sprachen_tabelle. 
[sprache_id] = tmb_tabelle.[sprache_id]) INNER JOIN tmb_link ON 
tmb_tabelle.[tmb_id] = tmb_link.[tmb_id];
```

**The value of the control D [MainLinkStoff] on C:**

```
=[stoffe_abfrage subform].[Formular]![stoff_id]
```

*(B is linked from [stoff_id] on B, to D)*

I want to use the primary key value on A in a button event on B, so I need a way to reference it. Unfortunately, referencing the primary key (stoff_id) on A from B only works if B is not empty. If there are no records on B, then the reference of stoff_id on A from B turns empty, event though the value of the control on A itself is nonempty.

---

**What I have tried:**

- I tried getting [stoff_id] from A and I have
  also tried getting the value from D,
  but both have resulted in the same issue. When B
  currently has no records, I get a runtime error because of an empty
  value.
- I was curious why this would be the case if getting the value
  directly from D for example, since that field has a
  value and is never empty. So I made a dummy textbox [dummyB] on
  B where my button is located
  in the header section and set the value to be equal to
  D.

*for the second test I tried 2 different approaches:*

1. Get D from C via parent

   ```
   =[Me].[Parent].[MainLinkStoff]
   ```
2. Get the D value manually from forms

   ```
   =Formulare![HUB]![NavigationSubform].Formular![MainLinkStoff]
   ```

In both approaches, if the chemical already has records in B, the dummy and D both display the value of the primary key correctly and are identical. If the chemical has no current records in B, D on the parent form displays correctly but the dummy is suddenly empty too. Why is this?  Here some images of what I mean. D is in the top middle of the form C, the dummy adjacent to it on the right subform B. A is on the left, B on the right. (invisible borders)

*[Existing records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGkBk.png)*

*[No existing records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzwPu.png)*

---

Comment: Part of problem may be binding forms to queries with INNER JOIN. Your table relationships are not clear to me, partly because of language barrier. If you want to create a new record, don't apply filter criteria, open form in AddRecord mode. How do you populate foreign key field when this data entry form opens?

Comment: I do open the form for data entry in AddRecord mode. [neutmb] is a pop up  that contains the primary key value [stoff_id]. There is a subform on [neutmb] which is linked to that primary key field. The Subform is where new entries are made and is in AddRecord mode. I specify the value of [stoff_id] I want from the button event, so [neutmb] opens to exactly that stoff_id, and the corresponding subform that is linked to it. There's a picture of my relationships in the description. Many names are in german, since it has to be read by other people who all work with access in german sry.

Comment: The problem is that I currently take the [stoff_id] value from the form that is potentially empty, then access doesn't know to which [stoff_id] to set [neutmb]. I tried getting the value from somewhere else, but for some reason it always turns empty when the original query from which the button is run is empty, even if the field from which I presumably take the value from, which is then not even located on that subform, is not empty. BTW, the [stoff_id] field's data on [neutmb] is taken from "chemikalien_tabelle".

Comment: Now you say [neutmb] is a form with a subform. I did look at the Relationships image but it didn't help. Sorry, this narrative is too difficult to follow and untangle without actually working with database.

Comment: Not really sure why the design of the data entry form matters. The whole issue is that I need a way to, from one subform A, reference the control of another subform B, both of which are located on the same main form C. It only works when B has existing records. When there are no existing records on B, the REFERENCE of the control on A from B suddenly turns empty, even though the actual VALUE of the control on A is nonempty. I think I'll just remove the whole data entry form from the question since it is too convoluted I agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the issue. I was working on the project from 2 different computers. One used the German language version of Access, the other the English language one. Object references created by wizards and internal tools in those versions use different formulations ([Forms]=[Formulare] etc.). What ended up happening was that some object references in SQL queries, criteria etc. were in German, the objects themselves had further references that were in English, which in turn referenced others that were in German again. This worked most of the time, but quite often, especially in fringe cases, it resulted in Access messing up the references completely. For example in cases where queries or field values were returned empty. I am not entirely sure how Access manages the conversion of references in different language versions, but there seem to be issues with it when mixing them. The solution was to choose one language version to use for references, and stick with that formulation for the entire project. I tested both, and either German or English work fine, on either version of accesss. Mixing them up within the same project however, creates problems.